# Got html5boilerplate - now what?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css

This is a very newbie question but I did not manage to find an answer to it.

I have the html5boilerplate in my rails application using comet. But how do I continue? Seems all h1-h5 are the same font size and tables are not styled in any specific style.

I originally wanted to have a simple CSS that has default styles for most elements like [Sinorcaish](http://www.zap.org.au/documents/styles/sinorcaish/example/index.html) or [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) so that I can start coding the website itself without worrying much about styling. Did I take the wrong library for this? Is there a css that goes on top of html5boilerplate to give me a nice style? should I use Blueprint/Sinorcaish on top of html5boilerplate?

Comment: html5boilerplate is not a Theme, it's more of a Framework.

Answer (score 3):

It's an overall reset type of HTML template. You would style the site without worry of too much differing between browsers that are HTML5-ready (actually, it's IE6-capable, too).

Use it, it's the bomb, believe me.

You could always just use a CSS reset stylesheet.

Comment: If I did not explain myself well - I understood what the purpose of the boilerplate. I just hoped it would also have a basic theme as well.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding! I must get my reading comprehension together! :) Perhaps the HTML5 Boilerplate isn't the solution. I tried finding themes for Blueprint, but had no luck.